# PHP submits form data instantly without button press

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, web

I'm making a form in HTML with bootstrap where when the user clicks on the submit button it submits the data to a json file on the server. The problem is that whenever i load the page it already submits a bunch empty data to the json file, and when i click the button it does nothing.
I have tried everything i thought of and can't find a solution. Maybe someone here can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

 $message = '';
 $error = '';

 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {

   if(file_exists('tickets.json'))
   {
      $current_data = file_get_contents('tickets.json');
      $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
      $extra = array(
        'titel'        => $_POST["titel"],
        'omschrijving' => $_POST["omschrijving"],
        'datum'        => $_POST["datum"],
        'naam'         => $_POST["naam"],
        'TicketType'   => $_POST["TicketType"],
     );
      $array_data[] = $extra;
      $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
      if(file_put_contents('tickets.json', $final_data))
      {
        $message = "<label class='text-success'>Ticket verstuurd!</label>";
      }
     }
    else
   {
       $error = 'No JSON File';
   }

 }

?>
```

This is the html bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
   </head>

    <body>

<script>
 var id;

 id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 1);
</script>

<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <?php
  if(isset($error))
  {
    echo $error;
  }
   ?>
 <div class="center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Titel">Titel</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titel" id="Titel">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Omschrijving">Omschrijving</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="omschrijving" id="Omschrijving" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Datum">Datum</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="datum" type="date" id="Datum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Naam">Naam</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="naam" type="text" id="Naam">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TicketType" id="TK_Rfc" value="rfc" checked>
     RFC
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TicketType" id="TK_Bug" value="bug">
     BUG
   </label>
 </div><br>
  <script class="center">document.write("#" + id);</script><br><br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
 </div>

 <?php
 if(isset($message))
 {
   echo $message;
 }
  ?>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>



</html>
```

Comment: There is no code in the HTML that will submit the page, so I guess `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {

   if(file_exists('tickets.json'))
   {` is executing when loading. Also NEVER call anything `name="submit"` in a form

Comment: Explaination for the `Also NEVER call anything name="submit" in a form` statement? Just qurious. Also, Roan, is the PHP and HTML in the same file? Are they two separate files? Try `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>` for the submit button?

Comment: Yes the html is in the same file with the php, I tried changing the button and now it doesnt submit anything at all.

Comment: Please update your code accordingly. It is confusing right now. Also, i hope the file is called `submit.php`?

Comment: Yes the file is called submit.php

Comment: @mplungjan _“Anything with name=submit will HIDE the form's submit event handler”_ - no, event handlers are not affected by this; but the `form` element has a `submit` _method_, and that would be overwritten by a field with the same name (due to the logic that makes named form fields accessible as `form[' fieldname']`.)

Comment: @Clemenz Correction: Anything with name=submit will overwrite the form's submit method and you will never guess this next time you want to submit the form from script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and you see it works.

The issue:

Since you said both html code and php code are in the same file, I set form action property to empty: 
`<form method="post" action="">`

Secondly, you need to name the submit tag like this so PHP code can trigger if condition:

`<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>`

Complete code:

```
<?php
$message = '';
$error = '';

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if (file_exists('tickets.json')) {
        $current_data = file_get_contents('tickets.json');
        $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
        $extra = array(
            'titel' => $_POST["titel"],
            'omschrijving' => $_POST["omschrijving"],
            'datum' => $_POST["datum"],
            'naam' => $_POST["naam"],
            'TicketType' => $_POST["TicketType"],
        );
        $array_data[] = $extra;
        $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
        if (file_put_contents('tickets.json', $final_data)) {
            $message = "<label class='text-success'>Ticket verstuurd!</label>";
        }
    } else {
        $error = 'No JSON File';
    }

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
        var id;
        id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 1);
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php
        if (isset($error)) {
            echo $error;
        }
        ?>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Titel">Titel</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titel" id="Titel">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Omschrijving">Omschrijving</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="omschrijving" id="Omschrijving" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Datum">Datum</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="datum" type="date" id="Datum">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Naam">Naam</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="naam" type="text" id="Naam">
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TicketType" id="TK_Rfc" value="rfc" checked>
        RFC
      </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TicketType" id="TK_Bug" value="bug">
        BUG
      </label>
    </div><br>
      <script class="center">document.write("#" + id);</script><br><br>

      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (isset($message)) {
        echo $message;
    }
    ?>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the comments below the question. It is not done to add the `name` attribute and set it to `submit` on the submit button. (I didn't know eirther)

Comment: @Clemenz , try to run my code and you see it works. The difference is if you set submit value but still set form action property incorrectly, it's still not working. My code came with some explanation. Please try it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` instead of `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`. Also you can use `<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">` instead of the button tag.

Hope this works for you. Veel succes!